# How to retrieve multiple property values from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, regex, grouping, extract

I have a JSON string:

```
x = '{"userId":"foo","traits":{"email":"foo@foobar.com"},"type":"identify"}'
```

that I want to get certain values from. I tried regex:

So far I have

```
anonId = x.match(/\"anonymous_id\"\:(.*?)/)?[1]
email = x.match(/\"email\"\:\"(.*?)\"/)?[1]
userId = x.match(/\"userId\"\:\"(.*?)\"/)?[1]
type = x.match(/\"type\"\:\"(.*?)\"/)?[1]
```

which is ugly and inefficient, but when I attempt to combine them:

```
[_, a, b, c, d] = x.match(/\"anonymous_id\"\:(.*?)|\"userId\"\:(.*?)|\"email\"\:(.*?)|\"type\"\:(.*?)/g)
```

the results that are returned are the entire group, instead of just the matched parts.

I want a,b,c,d to equal the value of keys, but instead I get:

```
Wanted:
**>> ["foo","foo@foobar.com","identify"]**
Actual results:
>> ["userId":"foo","email":"foo@foobar.com","type":"identify"]
```

Is there any way to achieve this in one line regex?

--- UDPATE ----

I ended up going with

```
  rxp = /\"user_id\"\:\"(.*?)\"|\"anonymous_id\"\:\"(.*?)\"|\"type\"\:\"(.*?)\"/g

  anonId = null
  userId = null
  type = null

  while (arr = rxp.exec(bdy)) isnt null
    userId = arr[1] if arr[1]
    anonId = arr[2] if arr[2]
    type = arr[3] if arr[3]
```

FWIW I'm avoiding using JSON.parse because I'm processing thousands of these and as I only need a small piece of it, I don't want the slowness of JSON.parse to impact the servers unnecessarily.

Comment: Why can't you use `JSON.parse()` and find values by doing iteration?

Comment: Your **question title** *`Javascript match extract multiple values string`* in hardly related to what you're actually asking for. Can you improve?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i wasn't sure how to phrase it exactly, open to suggestions though

Comment: You don't even need to iterate after doing `JSON.parse`. You just need to access the relevant properties with `obj.prop`.

Comment: You're assuming that `JSON.parse` is going to be slower than regexp; have you tested that? In fact, JSON parsers are usually quite fast. Anyway, if you have an "answer" to your own question, please add it as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: Actually, according to a little benchmark I ran, the JSON.parse solution is 30% slower than the regexp. Whether that is a lot or not is for you to judge, but for me, the "proper" approach of parsing the JSON and retrieving the fields you want is **much** easier and more robust that a regexp which will break the first time you throw something you hadn't thought about at it, such as an escaped double quote in a string, or an array-valued property.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
   var parsed = JSON.parse(x);
   anonId = parsed.anonymous_id;
} catch (ex) {
  //invalid json
}
```

That should work unless you have invalid JSON coming in. And then you might want to consider Regex but even then you might want to look at templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RegExp` `/[a-z@.]+(?=",|"})/ig` at single call to `.match()`

```js
var x = '{"userId":"foo","traits":{"email":"foo@foobar.com"},"type":"identify"}';
var res = x.match(/[a-z@.]+(?=",|"})/ig);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan See updated post. Should match all values of properties of object at OP

Comment: @guest271314 your answer was very very close to what i needed, thanks! Unfortunately your function would return values based on the order of the data provided, and I wouldn't really be able to know which value is userId, email etc as the data doesn't come from something i can control

Comment: It's a mystery why you would propose to parse JSON with regexp.

Comment: @torazaburo _"It's a mystery why you would propose to parse JSON with regexp"_ Requirement of Question; see OP at _"Is there any way to achieve this in one line regex?"_

Comment: How would you answer a question asking the best type of gun to shoot yourself in the head with?

Comment: @torazaburo _"How would you answer a question asking the best type of gun to shoot yourself in the head with?"_ Really ? Back to `js` , what is issue with approach ?

Comment: As just one example of how fragile trying to parse JSON with regexp is, your code fails on an example such as `{"foo": "bar\"baz"}`. it will fail if the JSON contains arrays, values other than strings, etc. A typical response to such concerns is that "it works on the OP's test data". Yes, but formats and data and requirements change. Instead of leading the OP down the garden path of using regexp, you should point him to the best practice which is to parse the JSON. He hasn't even validated his stated concern that JSON parsing is real slow, and I don't think it is.

Comment: @torazaburo @torazaburo Yes, `RegExp` would need, or could use  adjustments; depending on `JSON` string being parsed and expected results. If requirements change, would also have to possibly change parsing using an `js` object parser; there is no distinction there, that is, need to change portions of `js` when requirements change. _"He hasn't even validated his stated concern that JSON parsing is real slow, and I don't think it is."_, _"Actually, according to a little benchmark I ran, the JSON.parse solution is 30% slower than the regexp."_ Can you post link to benchmark ?

Comment: @torazaburo It would appear OP's concerns about differences between `RegExp` approach and `JSON.parse` approach are valid ?

Comment: No, my point is that a 30% performance penalty is a small price to pay when choosing between alternatives one of which (parsing and then extracting properties) will Just Work™, and the other of which will break the first time you breath on it. Let's say the server guy wakes up one morning and decides to switch to a new JSON library which serializes the properties in a different order. With the regexp approach, the order of the values in the resulting array will then change, and someone will be staying up late that night to find out why the app suddenly broke.

Comment: @torazaburo _"Let's say the server guy wakes up one morning and decides to switch to a new JSON library which serializes the properties in a different order."_ Not certain how you develop these hypothetical scenarios ? If that occurs the maintainer of the service should probably notify the users of the service at GitHub or by other means; otherwise even users employing `JSON.parse` approach may receive errors in their existing `js`. The order of properties should not matter. You do raise fair points. Provided solution using `RegExp` as that was requirement described at Question

Comment: I develop these hypothetical scenarios because I have seen them all, and I have sometimes been the one staying up late at night fixing such defects. I'm happy to hear about your huge trust in human nature and perfect communication. I have no idea what you mean by *`JSON.parse` approach may receive errors in their existing JS`*. `JSON.parse` will work for each and every case merely provided that the JSON is valid. You're right that *the order of properties should not matter*. My whole point (or one of my points) is that the regxp solutions **IS** dependent on the order of properties.

Comment: @torazaburo How is `RegExp` solution dependent on order of properties ?

Comment: Because the resulting array has elements in a specific order: `userID`, `email`, and `type`. He will be using the array in code which assumes that particular order. If the order of the properties in the JSON changes, the order of items in the array will change accordingly. Then his code which assumes that `res[0]` is the userID will no longer work. On the other hand, if he parses the JSON, and returns the array `[data.userId, data.traits.email, data.type]`, then the order will be guaranteed no matter what the order of the properties in the input JSON happened to be.

Comment: @torazaburo Could use `.replace()`, capture groups at `RegExp` for that case ? `JSON` is a `String` in `js` ; `String` methods should be able to be employed on the json string ?